# orthogonal projection- explicit formula

Tags: linear-algebra

I deleted the previous post.

I got the following sub-question in homework:

Let $V =\Bbb C^3$ with the standard inner product, and let $$v1 =
(i, 0,−2i), v2 = (i, i, 0)$$
(1) Find vectors $u1, u2,w1,w2$ of norm 1 so that $\langle u1,u2 \rangle=0, \langle w1,w2 \rangle=0$ 
and

$V1 := span (v1) = span (u1)$

$V2 := span (v2) = span (w1)$

$V3 := span (u1, u2) = span (v1, v2) = span (w1,w2)$

(2) For $i = 1, 2, 3$ let $Pr_{i}: V\to V_i$ be the orthogonal projection.
Find an explicit formula for each one of these.

**I really don't understand what to do in the the question (2).**

I thought about finding orthonormal vectors of $V1, V2, V3$, and then to use the formula: 
$$ \sum \langle v,u_i \rangle u_i$$ which is the orthogonal projection. My thought is that they meant by explicit formula for each one is to give $Pr_{i}(v)=$$ \sum \langle v,u_i \rangle u_i$ 
I'm right?

additional question: (3) Find $w\in V$ so that $Pr_{1}(w)\neq w, Pr_{2}(w) = w, Pr_{3}(w) = w$.

Comment: What are the $V_i$s?

Comment: @Bernard sorry, i didn't noticed. I added it now :)